# firefox 3.6 load css issue

Tags: css, firefox

since I updated my firefox to version 3.6, my site layout is broken.
My layout works fine in ie7 or firefox 3.5.7

I can see in firebug, in the net panel, that my css is correctly downloaded.
But in the css panel my css is truncated.

Does anyone has the same problem?
is there any explanation, solution or workaround?

Cheers

Comment: Can you give us a link to the site?  Or maybe post the CSS to http://pastebin.com/ or the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a very similar problem.  Check your CSS syntax carefully at just before the point where Firebug shows your CSS is truncated -- you might have a missing semicolon or end-brace that previous versions of Firefox silently fixed.

Loading the CSS file into an editor with syntax highlighting might help, as might the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Comment: I did the check, and I've one quote missing for an url background, thanks